# Why does std::set outperform std::priority_queue on std::vector and std::priority_queue on std::deque?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, containers, time-complexity

While implementing A* I experimented with three types of containers: `std::set`, `std::priority_queue` on `std::vector`, and `std::priority_queue` on `std::deque`.

The only operations I used were `push(e)`, `pop()`, and `top()`.

`push(e)` on `std::set` was implemented using `insert(e)` only. `pop` was `m_data.erase(m_data.begin())`, and `top()` was `*m_data.begin()`.

No extra implementation was done for `std::priority_queue` on `std::vector`, and `std::priority_queue` on `std::deque` for the given operations.

**With everything else unchanged, `std::set` worked somewhere around two times faster than the other two options.**

*Why is it so? If it is always true, why use `std::priority_queue` in terms of efficiency?*

P.S. The complexity of `push(e)` is `logn` (where `n` is the number of elements in the container) for all of them. The given implementation of `pop()` for `std::set` is amortized `const`, as indicated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase), and it is `logn` (where `n` is the number of comparisons) for the other two options, as indicated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop). `top` is `const` for all of them.

P.P.S. I don't quite get what `the number of comparisons` means [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop). Is it the depth of the heap?

The details on the implementation may be found [here](https://github.com/nestoroprysk/NPuzzleSimplified).

Comment: I just have a sneaky hunch that an `erase()` on the beginning of a vector requires copying all elements in the vector, from start to finish, but nothing of that sort with `std::set`. Just a gut feeling that I have. Surely you must understand that's how vectors work, right?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Per [`pop()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop) it should be calling `pop_back` which is `O(1)` for a `vector` or `deque`

Comment: Except that the question clearly states: "pop was m_data.erase(m_data.begin())".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That is for the `std::set` only

Comment: Optimized build?

Comment: I really don't get the confusion of the question.  `std::set` is `O(logN)` insert and `O(1)` removal.  The other two are `O(logN)` for both.  That means set should be faster, for a decently size container (vector might be faster for smaller data sets due to cache efficiency.)

Comment: `std::priority_queue` is usually implemented as a binary heap. Removing the smallest item from a min heap is likely more involved than removing the smallest item from a red-black tree like `std::set` usually uses

Comment: @NathanOliver One would think that being specifically designed for priority queue operations, `std::priority_queue` would be faster than a more general container like `std::set`. What's the point of `std::priority_queue` if `std::set` can do everything `std::priority_queue` can do faster?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations?

Comment: i mean, without seeing your code, who knows? post a minimal example. Also what platform/STL implementation are you trying this on?

Comment: I'm gonna guess that it's because you picked an element type for the priority queue that makes swapping elements too expensive.  We'll never know until you post the code.

Comment: The code’s a bot verbose. What exactly is missing?

Comment: @MattTimmermans There’s a struct with two ints and one pointer.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I didn’t change any levels of optimization (cmake . and then make).

Comment: @jwezorek I’m compiling on MacOS with C++17

Comment: Comparator<NotLess> is not a valid weak ordering, because it returns true for equal items.  Also, if you have a lot of equal cost items, the data comparison is expensive and unnecessary.  priority_queue will do more comparisons than set